# Does moving/ reallocating Pagefile.sys affect performance (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, pagefile

I've reallocated my pagefile to a different partition (1GB on primary partition and 4GB on a different one), does this affect any performance or cause any known issues in future? (My system has 4GB RAM)

Why I did it, I basically wanted to free up space on my windows primary partition so thought of moving hibernation file to a different partition but looks like its [not possible](https://superuser.com/questions/85369/how-to-change-location-of-hibernation-file-in-windows-7).

Since I can't move hibernate file, I reallocated the pagefile.

Comment: As Josh pointed out in his answer, moving a page file to another partition on the same physical drive gives you no performance benefit. Moving to a second physical drive will give some benefit, and moving to a SSD will be the most noticeable.

Comment: @Randolph: thank you. I've actually moved to a partition on a different drive, I guess that'd improve performance a little bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just moving it does not affect performance. If, however, you are relocating the pagefile.sys to a significantly faster drive - an SSD for example - you would see a significant difference in performance.

This assumes, of course, that your system relies on your pagefile heavily. If you have enough RAM in your system, there is little reliance on the pagefile and the perceived performance benefit will be minimal.

Comment: I agree with your first paragraph (+1), and disagree with the second (-1). A page file will always be in use by Windows, regardless of how much RAM is in the system. One just has to open up four virtual machines and your 8GB (or 16GB, or whatever) is quickly consumed. "Enough RAM" is subjective.

Comment: @randolph - You did not read what I said. I did not absolutely say that Windows does not rely on it AT ALL - I said "heavily" and "little" and "minimal". I also used the term "Enough RAM" because it is indeed subjective --- what is "enough" depends on the applications the user wants to use.

Comment: Page file is always in use as a preemptive backing store, but the logic is still sound; if you're doing little active paging, then it's a trivial difference in perceived performance.

Comment: Fine. I will vote you up. You've made your point.

Comment: @randolph LOL - had to fight hard for that upvote :) Hope I made a friend in the process

Comment: I needed to hear it from someone else's point of view :-)

Answer (score 2):

Issues?  No.  Performance?  If you're talking about multiple partitions on a single physical disk: It can't help.  Basically, this means that any access to the pagefile forces your disk to do a seek to a different partition.  Now, if this is a data partition that's going to see other access, then the performance hit won't be too severe.  If you'd created a dedicated partition at "the end" of your drive, then you'd effectively be forcing your drive to do full seeks every time it needed to touch the pagefile.

Now, if you've got multiple physical drives, then having pagefiles on multiple drives won't hurt anything.  If you system needs to write anything to a pagefile, then Windows will use the least busy drive available at the time, so access is spread out across multiple disks.