# Relocate the hibernation file (hiberfil.sys) on Windows 7

Tags: windows, ssd, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change location of hibernation file in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/85369/how-to-change-location-of-hibernation-file-in-windows-7)

I'm getting an SSD soon and to spare some wear I thought it'd be a good idea to keep the hiberfil.sys on the HDD.

Googling this question yielded that there is no such built-in option on Windows.
Can you think of any tricky/non-standard way to achieve just that?

Comment: Indeed it seems to be duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernation files are intentionally disabled on SSD volumes as a default policy in Windows 7. The boot time from SSD is comparable anyway so you won't be missing out on much, apart from having your session saved in place of course!

Comment: I didn't know hibernation files are disabled on SSDs. What would happen if I try to hibernate? Or is it just disabled? While a complete boot from SSD (non-hibernated state) might be faster than HDD hibernation, I sometimes need to save my current system state for long period of time where Sleep Mode is not an option

Comment: Hibernation writes the entire contents of your system memory to disk, which is a pretty quick way to wear out your SSD which you should write to very conservatively to maximize its lifespan. The disabling of hibernation file is a precautionary measure in order to ensure the drive is fit for purpose for as long as possible.

Comment: One thing also to bear in mind is the subject of SSD wear leveling, where the drive is written to in such a way that the most unused parts of the disk are used in every instance to increase live span.

Answer (score 0):

On that subject, it is impossible to move your hibernation file off the system partition. It essentially amounts to trying to move your boot files off of the boot drive.