# Blue screen of death using Hibernate in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, hibernate

The error below occurs every time hibernate is used in Win 7 Enterprise. Sleep, restart, and shutdown works fine.

I tried the command below, which is not working for me.

```
powercfg –h -size 100
```

No dump file is saved in Windows/Minidump. I enabled it [following this](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2010/07/27/how-to-configure-windows-to-create-minidump-files-on-bsod/).

[image]

[Similar issue but parameter 2 is different](https://superuser.com/questions/619665/bsod-internal-power-error-in-windows-7-on-hibernation)

**Update**
This is a 2 month old laptop, which I assume has latest drivers.

Comment: Based on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, it is because: "A fatal error occured while preparing the hibernate file." Is it related to graphics?

Comment: This is a 2 month old laptop, which I assume has latest drivers.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/619688/772515 This is what makes sense.

Comment: Try this: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3et1zk/having_bsod_internal_power_error_after_updating/

Comment: @iTechieGamer My windows is Win 7, graphic is NVida, both of which are different from that on the link.

Comment: I disabled my graphic driver, issue still exits.

Comment: Try to re-enable the hibernation feature by [disabling it through registry](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-and-re-enable-hibernation-using-microsoft-fix-it), restart the computer, and then enable it again.

Comment: @iTechieGamer I tried powercfg /hibernate off/on, but issue still exists.

Comment: I meant you to follow this:

You can also tweak the Windows Registry to enable or disable Hibernate. To do so navigate to the following key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power`. Give **HibernateEnabled** a value of 1 to enable Hibernation and 0 to disable Hibernation.

Comment: @iTechieGamer I don't think it will make any difference.

Comment: @iTechieGamer I tried the registry approach, same result.

Comment: Do you have enough space in your hard drive? If not, then that might be the cause. If so, then try defragging your hard drive.

Comment: There are enough space in hard drive.