# Windows 7 clean install taking up 71.6gb on my SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, storage

I installed windows on my SSD as the C:\ drive and it is 71.6gb used out of 111gb.

I should note that when I select all the folders in C:\ and right click and view properties of all the folders in the drive, they total 15gb.

What gives?  What is taking up a fake ~50gb?

Comment: Use WinDirStat or any alternative to determine your actual usage

Comment: It looks like pagefile.sys and hiberfil.sys are huge (~15gb).  I have 32gb of ram, should I disable the pagefile?  Whats hiberfil?

Comment: Hibernation....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment the additional space is being used by the `pagefile.sys` and `hiberfil.sys` files.

`pagefile.sys` is the Windows paging file which your computer will use to store running programs when your are running low on RAM. As you have a large amount of RAM (32GB), this file isn't likely to get frequent use (although it is still used even with large amounts of RAM). Whether to disable the paging file or not it up to you The following question discusses the pros and cons of disabling it.

[Any reason not to disable the Windows pagefile given enough physical RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/30345/any-reason-not-to-disable-the-windows-pagefile-given-enough-physical-ram)

`hiberfil.sys` is the Windows Hibernate file. Windows uses this file for both the Hibernate and Sleep functionality. When you request your computer to hibernate or sleep Windows will copy all of your RAM to the hard drive. This allows it to restore the system back to the state it was in before it was turned on. If you wish you can disable this functionality which will delete the file. Instructions for this can be found in this answer.

[Disable Windows Hibernate](https://superuser.com/a/402775/98211)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should install all windows updates. There's been an update that enables to delete backup files from windows update.
Then you can run a disc cleanup with windows tools.

You can disable suspend to disc (hiberfil.sys):

```
powercfg -h off
```