# Can I change the path and directory of the "hiberfil.sys" on Windows 8 due to reduce my C:\ disk usage?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, ssd, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change location of hibernation file in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/85369/how-to-change-location-of-hibernation-file-in-windows-7)

I have a SSD with 32GB and a HDD with 500GB on my notebook and after 3 months using Windows 8 it startd to warning me about C:\ disk usage (where Windows 8 is installed on). By looking on the [TreeSize](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) software, I noticed that C:\hiberfil.sys is using 7GB (Oo) of my SSD. I'm wondering on changing this file to D:\ (the 500GB HDD) due to reduce the Windows partition disk usage, is this possible? There are any another ways to deal with the hiberfile usage problem on Windows 8?

Comment: "There are any another ways to deal with the hiberfile usage problem on Windows 8?" -- yes, you can turn it off. Open an elevated command prompt (Start button > type: command > right click on it and select Run as Administrator > in the command prompt type: "powercfg hibernate off"  (no quotes)
That's the end of your hibernate file space issues

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following answer from [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-can-i-move-hiberfilsys/83ee0934-238d-4d8a-89b1-801a73d45ea8) to this very question should answer this question:

> You cannot.  Because the Hibernate File must be readable by the
>   bootloader, it must be stored on a specific sector of the hard drive,
>   on the primary system partition.  It cannot be moved.

Answer (score 15):

Complementing Ramhound answer:

> There are any another ways to deal with the hiberfile usage problem on
>   Windows 8?

I could not move it as Ramhound referenced, but I could [reduce the hiberfile.sys disk usage](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-performance/reduce-size-of-hiberfilsys-on-windows-8-rp/f2046905-07cf-4908-a768-a6d68e474e6b) by entering the folowind command on a elevated prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> ):

```
Powercfg.exe /hibernate /size 50
```

This command reduced the hiberfil.sys from 7GB to 4GB, releasing 3GB of free space (space enough to stop Windows 8 from frenetically warning about low space available on C:).