# is it possible to change location of hibernate file?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change location of hibernation file in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/85369/how-to-change-location-of-hibernation-file-in-windows-7)
>   [Can I change the path and directory of the “hiberfil.sys” on Windows 8 due to reduce my C:\ disk usage?](https://superuser.com/questions/507641/can-i-change-the-path-and-directory-of-the-hiberfil-sys-on-windows-8-due-to-re)

I'm using Windows 8 Pro. I like to hibernate and do use this feature several times every day. My laptop has one SSD (primary drive) and one HDD (in ultrabay).

I do want to move hibernate file from SSD to HDD because i don't want to "spent SSD limited resourced" and occupy extra-space, as I have 16 GB of RAM. So I want to move hibernate file from C: to D:.

How can I do that?

Comment: It is likely that you can't.  It wasn't possible in Win7 either:
http://superuser.com/questions/85369/how-to-change-location-of-hibernation-file-in-windows-7

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I change the path and directory of the "hiberfil.sys" on Windows 8 due to reduce my C:\ disk usage?](http://superuser.com/questions/507641/can-i-change-the-path-and-directory-of-the-hiberfil-sys-on-windows-8-due-to-re), itself a duplicate of [How to change location of hibernation file in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/85369/how-to-change-location-of-hibernation-file-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Win7, it is not allowed. [Here is an explanation from a MS MVP](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-can-i-move-hiberfilsys/83ee0934-238d-4d8a-89b1-801a73d45ea8):

> You cannot.  Because the Hibernate File must be readable by the bootloader, it must be stored on a specific sector of the hard drive, on the primary system partition.  It cannot be moved.

Knowing how the technology works, I would say NO for Win 8 also.