# Is It Possible To Share Page/Hibernation Files Between 2 Windows OSes?

Tags: hibernate, pagefile

I plan to install Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 (and Linux Mint) on my HDD. 8 will be installed first, then Server, then Mint. However, these 2 files can take up alot of space. So, is it possible to configure both OSes to share those files? If so, how can it be accomplished? I don't think it will hurt anything, since both OSes can't be booted up at the same time.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I assume you mean share their _locations_ via a symbolic link, not their contents...

Comment: No, I mean, is it possible to have both of the Windows OSes share the actual paging/hibernation files themselves, so that they both use the same files. But yes, I guess their location would have to be shared for this to happen. Would I place those 2 files in their own partition and then manually point both OSes to those files? How can it be done? And what about the swapfile.sys?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't want one to try to wake from hibernation with the data from the other. But I see what you mean, you want to have the disk space they use overlap and have them write over each other. I assume it's possible but I don't know how personally.

Comment: I have to agree with @MarcusChan - this is one to be treated with extreme caution.  I would be especially cautious about trying to share the swap file, but you may be able to share the hibernation file between the two windows installs.  Note - I haven't tested this and it may or may not work, but the approach I'd take is to have a dedicated drive or partition for the hibernation file, then set both Windows OSs to store the hibernation file in the same place in that drive/partition.  If that works, and you're desperate for the space, you could then try the same for the swap.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to share the files between the OSes. They contain information specific to the memory layout of each OS. While Windows 8 and 2012 are similar they are not the same. They have different DLLs that load into memory.

This is similar to why the hibernation file can not be moved (see [How to change location of hibernation file in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/85369/how-to-change-location-of-hibernation-file-in-windows-7/85372#85372)).

Raymond Chen explained the reasons why in this Windows Confidential article: [**The File System Paradox**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.11.windowsconfidential.aspx).

> Hibernation follows a similar pattern. Hibernating the operating system means
>   dumping the entire contents of memory into the hibernation file; restoring
>   from hibernation entails sucking that file back into memory and pretending
>   nothing happened. Again, it's another chicken-and-egg problem: to load the
>   hibernation file, you need the file system driver, but the file system
>   driver is in the hibernation file. If you keep the hibernation file in the
>   root directory of the boot drive, the miniature file system driver can be used instead.