# How do I patch NTOSKrnl.exe (or DLL, whichever applies to AMD system) to change drive/volume of hiberfil.sys in PopCreateHiberFile?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, patch

As seen here: http://superuser.com/a/1082931/31491

NTOSKrnl.exe Version 6.1.7601.24545
AMD64 system

Any other information needed? I am struggling to get the even the same view he had.

[image: My view, IDA Free]

All right, so the View > Sub-View > Pseudocode (F5) worked but it not nearly as readable as his and/or needs some tweaking as per:

https://hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/primer.shtml

Furthermore, pulling all the parts together requires some further knowledge of where to look (?).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

This article explains the solution [here](http://superuser.com/a/1082931/31491). I did not try it myself.

The idea was patching ntoskrnl.exe. The path consists of a basepath (looks like this: `\Device\Harddisk1\Partition0`) and the `\hiberfil.sys`. The basepath is stored statically in a variable called `IoArcBootDeviceName`. This variable itself is written in the function `IopCreateArcNames`. There it gets its value in these lines:

```
/* Create the global system partition name */
sprintf(Buffer, "\\ArcName\\%s", LoaderBlock->ArcBootDeviceName);
RtlInitAnsiString(&ArcString, Buffer);
RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString(&IoArcBootDeviceName, &ArcString, TRUE);
```

For this patch you need to install IDA or an comparable disassembler. For some help on what all this does you could use the [ReactOS-Reference](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d3/d82/ntoskrnl_2io_2iomgr_2arcname_8c.html). If your Pseudo-Code-View doesnt look like this, you should check your symbols [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/installing-windows-symbol-files).

Original:

The guy in the [article](http://superuser.com/a/1082931/31491) patched the function IopCreateArcNames. So first you need to go to this function instead.

There you need to replace this line:

```
sprintf(Buffer, "\\ArcName\\%s", LoaderBlock->ArcBootDeviceName);
```

with

```
sprintf(Buffer, "\\ArcName\\%s", LoaderBlock->ArcHalDeviceName);
```

Comment: Could you add some supporting information to your answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).